# Database Memoization?

Tags: database, performance, algorithm, memoization

Is a database a reasonable data structure for memoization? When extremely large amounts of data need to be cached, it may be unreasonable for an ordinary piece of software to actively maintain it in memory. A database makes it easy to store the results of calculations for later use, meaning calculations can be stopped and started at anytime without affecting a program's progress. If the database is shared, processing can also be distributed among multiple systems (a computer cluster).

My only reservation is that the delay caused by querying a database may impact algorithm performance, especially if an algorithm processes many permutations very quickly. Of course, database memoization would only be necessary if the space complexity of an algorithm / application is extremely high (gigabytes). Any thoughts?

Comment: by definition: memoization is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by having function calls avoid repeating the calculation of results for previously processed inputs

Comment: Yes, you've about got it.  In order to be worthwhile the costs of retrieval (and storage) need to be significantly less than the costs of re-calculation.

Comment: If you don't expect your memoization to stay in memory, that's a huge amount of data you're dealing with. A database might be a bit much though -- why not just `mmap` a giant file and let the OS deal with it? But make sure that the original calculation is not cheaper than a major fault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about large data to be answered on a single machine, the answer to this is almost certainly **NO!**  And on modern hardware, if the answer is not no, then either there is a pattern to the calculation, or the computation should be ruled infeasible.  But there are several variations where it can make sense.

The win with memoization is that the cost of recalculation is more than fetching your previous answer.  But if your answer fits in RAM, then there is no win to using a database since it is faster to just keep the store in memory.  So the only interesting case for the database is where the answer does not fit in RAM.

Let's suppose, for the sake of argument, that each key/value pair takes a whopping 640 bytes.  Let us suppose that you have 64 GB of RAM available to you.  So in order for it to not fit in RAM, you need over 100 million facts, which are created/accessed randomly.  However let's consider actual hardware.  These facts, when they don't fit in RAM, are stored in a hard drive.  The hard drive spins at, let's say, 6k RPM, or 100 times per second.  This makes the time to fetch/store a random piece of data an average of 1/200th of a second (on average you have to spin half-way to find your data).  So after you fill your data structure, to access it all again randomly takes 100 million * 0.005 s = 500,000 seconds which is nearly 590 days.  We're taking years just to access data (let alone create it) which is getting perilously close to the mean time between failure for the hardware.  (BTW there is some parallelism we can take advantage of here, hard drives cam look for several disk sectors they are looking for at a time, but that is limited and will not save you.)

The moral is that randomly accessing large data sets on disk is not feasible.  Even if you put a database in front of it.  Hard drives are not RAM, and should not be thought of as such.

But all is not lost.

A scenario where the database makes sense is your suggestion of a distributed computation.  If your computational steps are expensive, memoized calls are relatively few, and the data can fit in memory, then a database is very convenient.  Calls to the database will be fast (things are in memory), you can't simply keep things on a local hard drive (your data is spread out across multiple machines to use CPUs so there is no shared hard drive), and the database may be convenient simply because it is there.  (I've used databases this way before, and been very happy.)

However in this scenario the database is just a key/value store.  While a SQL database works, you may want to consider no-SQL solutions.  And once you go to no-SQL solutions you have options for data stores where data has been sharded such that it all fits in RAM, no matter how much data you have.  (Yes, you can shard relational databases as well.  eBay is a good example of a company that I know does, but once you do you tend to lose the "relational" part of it.  Yes, I know that several companies claim otherwise, their claims come with significant caveats.)

In fact when you do a Google search you are running against just this kind of sharded data store, which contains what is essentially memoized answers to a lot of questions about which pages match which key words, and which of those pages are most relevant.  Without memoization they could never do it.  But they also could never actually do it if they had to go to a hard drive for the answer.  (They're also not using SQL...)

Comment: That was a great answer. Thanks so much for your critical perspective!